# Error while Installing Apache Superset in AWS Amazon Linux 2 - ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'

Tags: apache-superset

Am trying to install apache superset by following the steps given in https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch

python3 --version
Python 3.7.10

Below are the steps I have executed:

1. sudo yum update
2. sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ libffi-devel python3-devel python3-pip python3-wheel openssl-devel cyrus-sasl-devel openldap-devel
3. python3 -m venv venv
4. . venv/bin/activate
5. python3 --version and python --version (Python 3.7.10)
6. superset db upgrade

at this step am getting below error:

```
(venv) [root@ip-172-31-40-125 ~]# superset db upgrade
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/venv/bin/superset", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('apache-superset==1.5.2', 'console_scripts', 'superset')())
  File "/root/venv/bin/superset", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/root/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 207, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/superset/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from flask import current_app, Flask
  File "/root/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jinja2 import escape
  File "/root/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .environment import Environment
  File "/root/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING
  File "/root/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/defaults.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS  # noqa: F401
  File "/root/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/filters.py", line 13, in <module>
    from markupsafe import soft_unicode
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/root/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)
(venv) [root@ip-172-31-40-125 ~]# python --version
`your text`Python 3.7.10



Help me out to install the superset successfully.
```